# how to passing value from shared function VB.Net to Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, function, shared

I have shared function on code behind as follow:

```
Public Shared idEvaluator As Integer

<WebMethod()>
<ScriptMethod()>
Public Shared Function Evaluate(ByVal user As Evaluator)
    Try
        Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BestEmployeeConnectionString").ConnectionString)
            connection.Open()
            Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO PENILAI(IDEMPLOYEE,IDPERIOD) VALUES (@IDEMPLOYEE,@IDPERIOD);SELECT @IDEVALUATOR=SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDEMPLOYEE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = user.IDEMPLOYEE
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDPERIOD", SqlDbType.Int).Value = user.IDPERIOD
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDEVALUATOR", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)
            cmd.Parameters("@IDEVALUATOR").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            IDEVALUATOR= Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters("@IDEVALUATOR").Value)   

                Return IDEVALUATOR

            End Using
        Catch __unusedException1__ As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Function
```

I just want to send value form IDEVALUATOR to javascript as follow:

```js
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Survey1.aspx/Evaluate",
            data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var t = '<%= IDEVALUATOR %>';
                alert(t)
            }
        });
```

when run alerts always produce a value of 0.but when debugging on shared function then the idevaluator shows the correct value. so, how can I get the value from a shared function at code behind in javascript?
thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Try just using response:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Survey1.aspx/Evaluate",
                data: '{user: ' + JSON.stringify(user) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var t = response;
                    alert(t)
                }
            });
```